# Install an npm dependency from git when it needs to be built via prepack npm-script

Tags: npm, build, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

I have a problem with getting a dependency from git, when that package ([vscroll](https://github.com/dhilt/vscroll) in my case) has "prepack" script, which runs when installing a git dependencies ([npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts)).

Getting from npm works fine:

```sh
npm uninstall vscroll && npm install --save vscroll
```

> removed 2 packages and audited 1568 packages in 6.593s 
> + vscroll@1.2.1 added 2 packages from 2 contributors and audited 1570 packages in 10.147s

Getting from git fails (specifying a commit, branch or tag produce the same error):

```sh
npm uninstall vscroll && npm install --save dhilt/vscroll
```

> removed 2 packages and audited 1568 packages in 5.992s
>
> > vscroll@1.2.1 prepack /Users/dhilt/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-b83f336d 
> > npm run build
>
> > vscroll@1.2.1 build /Users/dhilt/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-b83f336d 
> > node build
>
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834 
> throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'shelljs'
> ...

As you may see, the prepack script runs "node build" which starts with [shelljs requiring](https://github.com/dhilt/vscroll/blob/v1.2.1/build.js):

```js
const shell = require('shelljs');
```

which is not being installed in case of "npm install --save dhilt/vscroll".

Of course, npm stores an already built package, that can be just downloaded and used as is. But what should I do to use an unpublished version from git if it needs to be compiled? The final goal is to use a raw git-dependency in CI of the host package for the development purpose, so the prepack script should run and provide ready-to-use distributive in some way. Is this possible without publishing next/alpha/etc built versions on npm?

Comment: This is not a Git issue (though it sort of resembles one from the outside): the problem here is that the scripts you've chosen to use require `shelljs` so that they can run shell commands, and yet don't list the fact that they require `shelljs`, so your requirements file is not automatically updated. This is a bug in someone else's code, but you'll have to work around it by having your own explicit requirement to load shelljs.

Comment: The reason you can tell it's not a *Git* issue is this: if you were using, say, svn or hg instead of Git, you'd have exactly the same thing. So it's not the VCS that's the issue.

Comment: @torek Agree, thanks for removing 'git' tag